# How to convert a list of images into a Pytorch Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I have a list called `wordImages`. It contains images in np.array format with different width & height.

How Do I convert this into a tensor and use this instead of `my_dataset` in the below code?

Currently i am using this. But I need to save/read images

```
demo_data = RawDataset(root="output_craft/", opt=opt) 

demo_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                demo_data , batch_size=opt.batch_size,
                shuffle=False,
                num_workers=int(opt.workers),
                collate_fn=AlignCollate_demo, pin_memory=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `transforms` from the `torchvision` library to do so. You can pass whatever transformation(s) you declare as an argument into whatever `class` you use to create `my_dataset`, like so:

```
from torchvision import transforms as transforms

class MyDataset(data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, transform=transforms.ToTensor()):
        self.transform = transform
        ...
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        ...
        img_tensor = self.transform(img)
        return (img_tensor, label)
```

Comment: Hmm, I am still a bit confused. Since my images inside the list are of different width & height. Do I need to add padding and change them to same width/height?

Comment: How do I call this transformer? MyDataset(wordImages)? Really sorry. But  I googled a lot. I am new to Pytorch

Comment: To pass images of different dimensions, you will have to use `collate_fn`, here's a relevant thread: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-create-a-dataloader-with-variable-size-input/8278. It's a bit complicated though, padding might not be a bad idea.

Comment: Okay. Currently I am saving images in a folder then reading. But this is making me add few extra functions that decrease speed

Comment: This transformer basically applies function(s) onto your numpy array, so it can be called like normal python functions by `img_tensor = self.transform(img)`

Comment: Functions like empty the folder, then write images, then pytorch read them again in memory.

Comment: My main motive is speed. I hope collect_fn is not slower

Comment: The image tensors are only converted once, which should not be too time exhaustive (they're not converted every epoch). But if you want, it's possible to save tensors to file for loading: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/save-a-tensor-to-file/37136